# What is the best way to power source small Robot

Tags: power, first-robotics

I am trying to make a small robot with 4 12 v DC Motor + Raspberry PI + camera possibly a USB camera.

I am very confused with power source.
Is it possible to get all of them powered by a single power source? Can you recommend some of them?  I am really in a need.
Also is there any software where I can design electric circuit of this robot before burning my actual hardware.

Edit:
I have 4 dc 
 12 v motors with 60 mamp without load and  300 mamps with load and it have torque of 1.5 kgcm

Comment: Welcome on Robotics @RahuIAN, for power source there are two important factor the voltage and the amps. Please complete your questions with the current consumption of your devices

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend using only one source of energy on your robot otherwise, you could have some grounds problems.

Your motors are not consuming a lot (max ~ 1.2 Amps) and you can consider that the Raspberry Pi could consume up to 3A if you plug your camera (Could be less but with 3A your are safe).

So in your case, I would use a 12V battery with a DC/DC converter to power to Raspberry Pi in 5V (Here you need to make sure that the converter can deliver 3 A in 5V from a 12V source, like this [one](https://www.ebay.de/itm/DC-DC-Konverter-Converter-Spannungswandler-12V-5V-3A-15W-GE-/172984850724)).

For the kind of battery, if you don't care about the size, capacity, weight etc you can go for a Lead–acid battery that is cheap and easy to use (Like this [one](https://www.toolstation.com/shop/Electrical/d190/Batteries+and+Powerbanks/sd2450/Sealed+Lead+Acid+Battery/p79562)). Otherwise, you can check for a Lithium-ion battery for example that has more capacity for the same size/weight. Lithium batteries are mostly more expansive and could be dangerous if you are not charging/discharging properly.

Comment: It really doesn't matter how many power sources you use, as long as they all use a common ground.

Comment: Can you recommend any design software where I can simulate the circuit.?

Comment: I don't know much about circuit simulation but can have a look at Simulink from Matlab